# Axios json response is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, axios

i am sending a request to opensea api and trying to log the `trait` data. an example of the entire response is in pastebin url. thank you for taking the time to review this.
https://pastebin.com/ugQHjbn1

```
var axios = require("axios").default;

var r = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets',
    params: { order_direction: 'desc', offset: '0', limit: '1', collection:`enter code here` 'brotchain' }
};

axios.request(r).then(function (response) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data.assets.token_id));
}).catch(function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is that the `assets` inside the data is an array, basically, you can not do `response.data.assets.token_id` because there is no `token_id` on an Array `[]`.

In order to display each one of the assets, you need to loop over the array and then show the asset info or whatever property inside of it.

here is your code showing all the `token_id` of each entry and their `traits`

note: in the future it will help to see the full response and act using the different structures that are defined there.

```js
var r = {
  method: 'GET',
  url: 'https://api.opensea.io/api/v1/assets',
  params: {
    order_direction: 'desc',
    offset: '0',
    limit: '1',
    collection: 'brotchain'
  }
};

axios.request(r).then(response => {
  const assets = response.data.assets;

  assets.forEach(asset => {
    console.log("token id of the asset", asset.token_id);
    console.log("now we will show all the traits for this asset")
    console.log(asset.traits);
    console.log("end of the asset");
  })
}).catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you i wish i actually saw this before

Comment: no worries @boat if it is the correct answer, you can mark it!

Comment: did so, thank you!